# Rails with Backbone does not save has_many data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I am really unexperienced in rails. I may be doing things that are unkosher.  If so let me know.
I am attempting to save `has_many` data where a `group` `belongs_to` `building`.  And `building` `has_many` `groups`.  I am sending data to rails as JSON from backbone.

```
{
max: "10"
max_age: "70"
min_age: "50"
name: "new group"
building: "kvbmPQQo"
}
```

In my groups_controller.rb I tried to find the `building` first by the `id_token` and then save the group with said building.

```
def create
  @building = Building.where(:id_token => params[:building]).first
  @group = Group.new(group_params)
  @group.building = @building
  @group.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @group }
  end
end
```

When I run this I don't know exact what the problem is. **It does not save.** Here is what is being logged in the terminal.

```
Started POST "/groups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-21 06:48:04 -0500
Processing by GroupsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"G", "max"=>"2", "min_age"=>"2", "max_age"=>"2", "building"=>"kvbmPQQo", "group"=>{"name"=>"G", "min_age"=>"2", "max_age"=>"2"}}
  Building Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "buildings".* FROM "buildings" WHERE "buildings"."id_token" = 'kvbmPQQo' ORDER BY "buildings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Also if you see something that I am doing in a completely un "rails way" please let me know. 
My `groups.rb` has `belongs_to :building` and my `building.rb` has `has_many :groups`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create

  # Find the building by its token
  @building = Building.find_by(:id_token => params[:building])
  # or
  # @building = Building.where(:id_token => params[:building]).first

  # Create a new building group with parameters
  @group = @building.groups.create(params[:group])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @group }
  end

end
```